# PHP - Redirect back to previous page, without any form

Tags: php, html, redirect, header, web

On my website I offer the visitors 4 languages. I have a dropdown list at the top-right of the site where they can choose their language. When you press an item in the dropdown list you get sent to /en, /pl, /pt, /se (depending on which language you chose).

Inside for example the /pl (polish) folder, I put this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['lang'] = "pl";
header('Location: ../');
exit;
?>
```

I then just re-direct them to the front page, where I check if the lang is pl, then use the Polish text.

But now I want it to re-direct them to the specific page they were on prior to pressing the item in the dropdown menu.

If they were browsing the /news page, I want them to be re-directed there and not the front page.

I just cannot seem to do this. Is this even possible?

I know I can do it with a form, and insert a hidden input. But this is without a form!

Here's my dropdown menu:

```
<!-- Language Settings -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo menu8; ?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="en">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="pt">Portugu&ecirc;s</a></li>
        <li><a href="pl">Polski</a></li>
        <li><a href="se">Svenska</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<!-- End Language Settings -->
```

Comment: How would I do that? Any code examples?

Comment: Yes I know how to translate the site, I have done that. My problem is that it doesn't redirect back to the previous page. I checked your link and couldn't see anything about redirecting to previous page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$_SERVER` super global. `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. This will be the address of the page the user came from.

Comment: so do I just put that at the top of every page on my website? `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and then in the PHP file, what would it look like? Sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: Use it to set your header. `header('Location:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do I simply just put `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`  below the session_start() in my /news page. Nothing else? And then the `header('Location:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` in my /pl file? Or do I assign it to some variable. Like `$currentpage = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`and then redirect to $currentpage ?

Comment: I get this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'HTTP_REFERER' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\index\pt\index.php on line 6` when I put `header('Location:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

Comment: You don't need to assign it to a variable to use it. Put it after your `session_start()` and `$_SESSION['lang'] = 'pl'` calls or that data won't be saved

Comment: It will not be set if you go directly to the page.

Comment: This causes a problem on the landing page. On the landing page is where you initially choose a language. When I went there manually, by typing in the url, and tried to choose a language to enter the site, it kept redirecting me to the landing page. Is there a way to check like "if its not landing page, redirect me. else; do not redirect" @Jaime

Comment: Hahhaha this causes a tremendous problem. Now the users can't enter the actual website. Because it re-directs them to the landing page! Hahaahh